# Reorder SharePoint grouping

Tags: list, grouping

I have my SharePoint list grouped by Status but they are not being ordered in numerical order.

I want them to be ordered as

```
1. Status Name
2. Status Name
```

*etc*

```
10. Status name
11. Status Name
```

They are currently displayed as

[image: List screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its possible for you to rename the status texts, you can prefix them with zeroes and so, to make alphanumeric sorting possible. Of course its not a nice solution in a production environment where people are allready using them, but if its under development it could be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well the Status column is not of Number type, but of type Text. Hence SharePoint sorts it like text. For example, it is not easy to correctly sort "10a" in your snippet above

Comment: Not easy or not possible?

Comment: OOTB, not possible. with super awesome custom XSLT: probably possible ;)

Comment: Actually, adding zeroes at the beginning should sort your groups right. You should experiment about adding the named sub-points (a), but you can still make it work if you stick to a good naming convention. For example - always put interval after the number, and then put the letter.

Comment: @PetyaG, That is a quite ugly solution but surely doable ;) And it relies on the fact that OP can rename the status texts

Comment: Of course there is an option to do it pretty - like you said through xslt. But it again involves changing the status names. For example you can create your own numbered prefix that will not be rendered on the end user view. Groups will still be sorted by their 'true' value (with the prefix) - not the one rendered on the page.

Comment: I think I'm gonna have to re-name them. Unfortunately they are already in use but super awesome custom XSLT is beyond me!

Answer (score 0):

Group by status with Ascending. My status column is a Choice column with status choices in the same order.

[image: I don't have any problem]